# I need to rearrange the rows of a matrix according to the sum of its positive even elements

Tags: c++, sorting, matrix

So I have to rearrange my matrix depending on the sum of the positive even numbers of each row.

I have no errors in my syntax but the sorting isn't quite doing the job sometimes it works sometimes it just rearrange randomly,here is what I got so far.

[image]

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

#define m 4
#define n 3
//create and fill a matrix
void fill_random(int matrix[n][m], int max) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = (rand() % max) +1;
        }
    }
}
//find even on each row
void find_even(int max, int matrix[n][m], int even = 0) {
    cout << "The even numbers of this matrix are: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] % 2 == 0) {
                cout<< matrix[i][j]<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
//sum of even in each row
void row_sum(int row_total, int matrix[n][m]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            row_total = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j] % 2 == 0) {
                    row_total += matrix[i][j];
                }
            }
            cout << "Row " << i << " total "<<"--> " << row_total << endl;
        }
    }
//sort  
void Sort(int& a, int& b) {
        int tg;
        tg = a;
        a = b;
        b = tg;
    }
//sorting matrix (here is my problem it doesn't work all the time)
void sortedMatrix(int matrix[n][m]) {
        int a[3][3];
        row_sum;
        Sort;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (matrix[i] < matrix[j]) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                        Sort(matrix[i][k], matrix[j][k]);
                    }
                    Sort(a[i][j],a[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                printf("%5d ", matrix[i][j]);
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }


    }

    int main(void) {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int matrix[n][m];
        fill_random(matrix, 10);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                printf("%5d ", matrix[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");

        }
        cout << endl;

        cout << "---------------------------------------- \n";
        find_even(10, matrix, 0);
        cout << "---------------------------------------- \n";
        row_sum(0, matrix);
        cout << "---------------------------------------- \n";
        cout << "The sorted matrix will be: \n";
        cout << endl;
        sortedMatrix(matrix);
return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What is the first parameter of the function find_even doing?

Comment: This if statement if (matrix[i] < matrix[j]) { does not make sense.

Comment: And what is the array int a[3][3]; doing here?

Comment: when you say you want to sort. do you mean the row with the smallest even sum becomes the first?